# Zero clipboard is not working in gwt

Tags: gwt, gxt, jsni, zeroclipboard

I have been trying to integrate zero clipboard library with gwt code as follows.

**test.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="test/test.nocache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script language="text/javascript">

     function initZeroClipboard() {
                   ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('ZeroClipboard.swf');
       }

</script>

 .....................................
  //Intial body load instantiating 'Moviepath'

  <body onload="initZeroClipboard();">
```

**TestWidget.java**

```java
Anchor copy = new Anchor("Copy");
......................
 //setting id to refer the movie
copy.getElement().setId("copyId");
glueCopy("Hello World");
 ...........
 //Native method
public static native void glueCopy(String text) /*-{
 var clip = new $wnd.ZeroClipboard.Client();
 clip.setText(text);
 clip.glue('copyId');
}-*/;
```

**But on intial load itself i am getting the following error in IE and FF.**

**Jetty Server IE error** 
[image]

**Jetty server FF error**
[image]

I have donloaded 'ZeroClipboard.swf' and 'ZeroClipboard.js' files from the following
**https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard**

Can anyone come across this issue, if so suggest me how to get rid of this.

Comment: is your ZeroClipboard.js  loading properly ? I mean path.

Comment: @The Suresh Atta, No issue in loading 'ZeroClipboard.js', i have seen it is loaded in Jetty Console

Comment: consider an alternative for ZeroClipboard, as it's not maintain anymore. see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596934/547020).

Comment: @Eliran Malka , Does it work if it is written as gwt code as JSNI method.

Comment: Error occurs whenever 'ZeroClipboard' library related code is placed in JSNI method. If we keep the same java script code in 'html' it is working fine with out any issues.